# extracting all lines from file that are between two patterns

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a text file tat contains patters .' (a period followed by a single quote) and '. (a quote followed by a period). I want to extract all the lines from .' to '. using awk or grep .

```
`lasjdalsjd  
 ljsdlasdkj.'lsjdlsjd  
 wqeuoqweui0  
 90u402394ewlrj  
 lwejwerj  
 '.  
 klfjksldkjfsdlfkj  
 dslfslfkjdsf
```

In the above text I want to extract

```
lsjdlsjd  
wqeuoqweui0  
90u402394ewlrj  
lwejwerj
```

separately. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

With the sample data you have provide, this works

```
 awk "/\.'/, /'\./{sub(\".*[.]'\", \"\"); sub(\".*'[.]\", \"\");print}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed you can do:

```
sed -n "/\.'/,/'\./{s/^.*\.'//; s/'\..*$//; p;}" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Most regex libraries include a multi-line flag.  For example in Perl the "m" flag:

```
perl -ne "BEGIN{undef \$/;} print \$1 while (/'(.*?)'/smg)" yourfile
```

Note I've coded this particular search to be non-greedy so it will also find multiple sets of '..' strings in your file.